# How to use WebLogic configured connection pool (with JNDI Name) in Spring Hibernate Oracle DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm fairly new at this and I'm stuck. If someone could help, that would be great.
My code right now uses inbuilt connection pool, how to change to  Weblogic configured connection pool ? My code right now is as below:

hibernate-cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>

<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

<!-- Configure BLOB/CLOB settings in hibernate -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</property>

<!--Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</property>
        <property name="max_fetch_depth">3</property>

<!-- Bind the getCurrentSession() method to the thread. -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>


</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Hibernate Session Class that has the getSession method:

```
public class HibernateSession {


     public Session getSession() {

     Configuration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();

     configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", USERNAME);
     configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", PASSWORD);
     configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", DB_URL);
     configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
     SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

     return session;
     }
}
```

Hibernate version: 4.2.11.Final
Weblogic: 10.3.6

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JNDI lookup to look up the datasource you configured via WebLogic Admin console.